# Rails Website Login not working in production (Heroku)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, authentication

I am creating a Rails application containing a Login. In development everything is fine. Login in production (Heroku) fails.

As I am new to RoR I follow this [Basic Tutorial](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/account_activation). The App contains a "User" model. The user has a boolean attribute "activated" as an account needs to be activated after the signup. During login there is an statement (see sessions_controller.rb):

```
if user.activated?
```

which is true in development and false in production.

I pushed the database with seeds.rb. On other pages I can see content, also initialized with seeds.rb, so I think it is no general database issue.

As the databese seems to be okay and it runs in development I assume I just missed something, which is hard to detect for me as a newbie and hopefully easy to detect for an experienced programmer.

Here is a part of my code. Say if you need more.

sessions_controller.rb:

```
def create
user = User.find_by(email: params[:session][:email].downcase)
if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
  if user.activated?
    log_in user
    params[:session][:remember_me] == '1' ? remember(user) : forget(user)
    redirect_to changenews_path
  else
    message  = "Account not activated. "
    message += "Check your email for the activation link."
    flash[:warning] = message
    redirect_to root_url
  end
else
  flash.now[:danger] = 'Invalid email/password combination'
  render 'new'
end
end
```

This checks if the user who is logging in is already activated. In production it leads to "else > message [...]".

my Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails',        ' 5.1.6'
gem 'bootstrap', ' 4.2.1'
gem 'puma',         ' 3.9.1'
gem 'sass-rails',   ' 5.0.6'
gem 'uglifier',     ' 3.2.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', ' 4.2.2'
gem 'jquery-rails', ' 3.1.0'
gem 'turbolinks',   ' 5.0.1'
gem 'jbuilder',     ' 2.7.0'
gem 'coffee-script-source', ' 1.8.0'
gem 'bcrypt',         ' 3.1.12'
gem 'popper_js', ' 1.14.5'
gem 'font-awesome-sass', ' 5.8.0'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3', ' 1.3.13'
  gem 'byebug',  ' 9.0.6', platform: :mri
end

group :development do
  gem 'web-console',           ' 3.5.1'
  gem 'listen',                ' 3.1.5'
  gem 'spring',                ' 2.0.2'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', ' 2.0.1'
end

group :test do
  gem 'rails-controller-testing', '1.0.2'
  gem 'minitest',                 '5.10.3'
  gem 'minitest-reporters',       '1.1.14'
  gem 'guard',                    '2.13.0'
  gem 'guard-minitest',           '2.4.4'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.18.4'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

I tried to set all gems to the latest version ('>= X.Y.Z') and do "bundle install", but there was no effect.

and the Heroku log (extract):

```
:23.352114+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [:23.352005 #4]  INFO -- : [shortened] Started POST "/login" for 77.183.95.212 at 2019-04-09 11:43:23 +0000

:23.353232+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [:23.353123 #4]  INFO -- : [shortened] Processing by SessionsController#create as HTML

:23.353509+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [:23.353266 #4]  INFO -- : [shortened]   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"shortened", "session"=>{"email"=>"mymail@mymail.de", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Log in"}

:23.356478+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [:23.356409 #4] DEBUG -- : [shortened]   [1m[36mUser Load (0.8ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = $1 LIMIT $2[0m  [["email", "mymail@mymail.de"], ["LIMIT", 1]]

:23.432392+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [:23.432248 #4]  INFO -- : [shortened] Redirected to https://myappname.herokuapp.com/
```

I can't get any information from the debug message. And i I have no clue what the "LIMIT" stands for. I hope someone of you knows an answer to my problem.

So usually I expect the login to be successful, as the database seems to be okay. Currently user.activated? ist false in Heroku.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: run `heroku run rails c` and check if you have proper data in the database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Heroku runs bundle install when you push the code so you dont need to run this.
2. Did you run `heroku run db:seed` to actually seed your database?
3. If you did, you can run `heroku run rails c`, then `u = User.all` and manually check by looking at the output that the users have correctly been seeded.
4. (opinion) I would suggest using the "devise" gem for users/logins etc.. but feel free to use whatever you are more confortable with.
5. Please use the heroku logs to give us (and yourself) a better understanding of what is wrong by running `heroku logs -n 200`, 200 being the number of lines to display.

Comment: Thank you! As I ran 'heroku run rails c' I realised in the productiondatabase:  'activated=false'. So I obviously did some mistake while pushing the database. Now it's fine. - Well, most times the problem is in front of the PC *facepalm*